# Calluses under big toe

Tags: running, vibram, running-form

I've recently switched to vibram five fingers and have started developing calluses under my big toe. Is this normal or is my strike wrong?

Comment: Impossible to tell without video analysis. However, calluses are just natural reactions to friction, so entirely probably that it's just a normal adaptation to the VFF's.

Comment: Theoretically you're strike can't be wrong if you're wearing five fingers....

Comment: Sure it can @MDMoore313, why else would some people get stress fractures from running with them?

Comment: switched to a forefoot strike

Comment: @IvoFlipse I'm with you, was being a lil on the sarcastic side, since Five Fingers' whole thing is that you're running the way you're naturally supposed to when you have them on. Maybe not a lol but a chuckle..?

Comment: @MDMoore313 - In my assessment, VFF's are nothing more than capitalizing on a fad. There are millions of runners over the past 50 years that have run just fine in all kinds of shoes, and all of a sudden we all have to switch to minimal shoes and forefoot strikes? Research chi/pose and similar and see the rise in injury rates. People hate hearing it, but the VAST majority of runners self select the best stride/strike pattern for them. And heel striking does NOT mean heel touching first. There are almost NO elite runners where the heel does not touch first.

Comment: @JohnP I'm with you, no two people can run alike (and VFFs are a fad), I'm a forefoot runner but that's what I've adapted to after all this time.

Comment: lot of opinions, no answers.

Comment: @prat - That's because it's impossible to tell why you have a callus. Most likely it's because your VFF's rub your feet in a different way and it's a normal adaptation, but there's no way to definitively say "This is why".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have had a lot of experience with the vff (3+ years personal) and from what you're telling us you most likely have girly feet that have never had a chance to develop calluses. Get barefoot more often and as long as your calluses aren't ripping off you're fine.
Look at the bottom of anyones foot who runs a lot and you will notice both the outside of the big toe, midfoot and heel are pretty callused up, something to be proud of, not worry about.

Answer (score 0):

We can't debug your stride from just the information that a new callus formed. New calluses pop up sometimes. Probably it's because you switched footwear. Whether there's a problem is impossible to determine from what we know.